# Qt5.6.0 on Windows x64 with MSYS2 - Unknown modules: widgets core gui

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt5 project where I want to exclude extra dependencies such as ICU, openssl etc since these are not needed.

I am using MSYS2 environment for building application and therefore needed to build Qt in same environment.

The final configuration for building (the only that would result in successful compilation) looked like this:

```
./configure -prefix /usr -no-opengl -no-icu -no-dbus -no-fontconfig \
-no-harfbuzz -no-freetype -no-compile-examples -nomake tests \
-skip qtwebview -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtandroidextras \
-skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdeclarative \
-skip qtdoc -skip qtenginio -skip qtlocation -skip qtmacextras \
-skip qtmultimedia -skip qtscript -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialbus \
-skip qtserialport -skip qtsvg -skip qttranslations -skip qtwayland \
-skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebsockets \
-skip qtwebview -skip qtwinextras -skip qtx11extras \
-skip qtxmlpatterns -skip qttools -platform win32-g++
```

I used `-prefix /usr` to install built libraries and binaries into my MSYS2, but after I try to run `qmake` in project location I get error:

`Unknown QT modules: widgets gui core`

I verified that all needed DLLs are in right places and .h are all available but still cannot understand why qmake does not know about these modules after all?

Searching online for similar error gives a lot of useless output..

**UPD**: Output of `config.summary`

```
$ cat config.summary

   Configure summary

Build type:    win32-g++ (x86_64, CPU features: mmx sse sse2)

Build options:
  Configuration .......... accessibility audio-backend avx avx2 build_all c++11 c++14 c++1z clock-gettime clock-monotonic concurrent debug debug_and_release full-config getaddrinfo large-config medium-config minimal-config no-freetype no-harfbuzz openssl pcre png precompile_header qpa qpa reduce_exports reduce_relocations release shared small-config sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 system-zlib
  Build parts ............ libs tools examples
  Mode ................... debug and release; default link: debug
  Using sanitizer(s)...... none
  Using C++ standard ..... c++1z
  Using gold linker....... no
  Using new DTAGS ........ no
  Using PCH .............. yes
  Using LTCG ............. no
  Target compiler supports:
    SSE2/SSE3/SSSE3 ...... yes/yes/yes
    SSE4.1/SSE4.2 ........ yes/yes
    AVX/AVX2 ............. yes/yes

Qt modules and options:
  Qt D-Bus ............... no
  Qt Concurrent .......... yes
  Qt GUI ................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............. yes
  Large File ............. yes
  QML debugging .......... yes
  Use system proxies ..... no

Support enabled for:
  Accessibility .......... yes
  ALSA ................... no
  CUPS ................... no
  DirectWrite ............ no
  Evdev .................. no
  FontConfig ............. no
  FreeType ............... no
  Glib ................... no
  GStreamer .............. no
  GTK theme .............. no
  HarfBuzz ............... no
  Iconv .................. no
  ICU .................... no
  Image formats:
    GIF .................. yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
    JPEG ................. yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
    PNG .................. yes (in QtGui, using bundled copy)
  libinput................ no
  Logging backends:
    journald ............... no
    syslog   ............... no
  mtdev .................. no
  Networking:
    getaddrinfo .......... yes
    getifaddrs ........... no
    IPv6 ifname .......... no
    libproxy.............. no
    OpenSSL .............. yes (loading libraries at run-time)
  NIS .................... no
  OpenGL / OpenVG:
    EGL .................. no
    OpenGL ............... no
    OpenVG ............... no
  PCRE ................... yes (bundled copy)
  pkg-config ............. yes
  PulseAudio ............. no
  QPA backends:
    DirectFB ............. no
    EGLFS ................ no
      EGLFS i.MX6 ........ no
      EGLFS i.MX6 Wayland. no
      EGLFS EGLDevice .... no
      EGLFS GBM .......... no
      EGLFS Mali ......... no
      EGLFS Raspberry Pi . no
      EGLFS X11 .......... no
    LinuxFB .............. no
    Mir client............ no
    XCB .................. no
  Session management ..... yes
  SQL drivers:
    DB2 .................. no
    InterBase ............ no
    MySQL ................ no
    OCI .................. no
    ODBC ................. yes (plugin)
    PostgreSQL ........... no
    SQLite 2 ............. no
    SQLite ............... yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
    TDS .................. no
  tslib .................. no
  udev ................... no
  xkbcommon-x11........... no
  xkbcommon-evdev......... no
  zlib ................... yes (system library)
```

Comment: QTDIR is set correctly? It should show to your installation path. PATH should also contain this.

Comment: @KimKulling QTDIR must be in my env? Such as `export QTDIR=/usr`?

Comment: @KimKulling Just checked, but QTDIR does not change anything. `/usr/bin` is in path, not sure that makes the need for `/usr` to be in path...

Comment: Hm, when you are working in a posix-like console I guess you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well. The error is an indicator that in your environment the dlls cannot be found. So make sure that this is not the case.

Comment: It is set correctly as with  a plain C++ code (without Qt) I can link other libs such as `libstdc++.dll`

Comment: QTDIR is not relevant since Qt 4.0.0. Can you add the output of configure (saved in `config.summary`) to the post?

Comment: @peppe Added `config.summary`. Please help me check if it looks correct.

Comment: Could you please also add your `.pro` file that you're running qmake on?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but QtGui requires OpenGL. You don't appear to have an enabled QPA backend (I may be wrong).

Comment: @JonHarper I don't think it would allow me to build Qt5Gui.dll without OpenGL in that case. But it is build and seems to be correct.

Comment: I wonder if MSYS is even supposed to be supported, you've got no QPA plugin compiled.

Comment: @peppe well official documentation (if I can call it that) on wiki.qt.io says that if I want to build amd64 applications on Windows with MinGW I should use MSYS2.

Comment: That's a wiki, not official documentation -- the official docs are https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html or https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html , they don't seem to talk about MSYS2, but again I'm by no means a Win32 expert. The fact that you're using a *UNIX* configure makes me feel something is wrong, that's all.